# How to store environment variables in a Python Flask app?

Tags: python, flask, environment-variables

I have a Python Flask app that accesses the Github API. For this I need to store an access token. What is the common practice to store that data and how do I access that inside my app?

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['DEBUG'] = True


@app.route('/',methods=['POST'])
def foo():
   ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simpliest way is to place it into configuration module (regular python `.py` file) and then `import` and use it in your code as suggested by [this snippet](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/2/) on Flask site.

Comment: I was thinking about this possibility and wasn't so sure, until now. For example, regarding the Built-in Configuration Variables from Flask, I didn't found variables for `host` and `port` which are used on `app.run()`. So, this approach is useful. Thanks :)

Comment: the link is no longer available. Can you please update your answer?

Answer (score 6):

Flask has a custom context to store app variables:

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/appcontext/

You can use g object to store your variables:

```
from flask import g
g.github_token = 'secret'
```

And after initialization:

```
from flask import g
token = g.github_token
```